# Errors when using std::deque<std::string>

Tags: c++, string, deque

When I use a std::deque as a private member in my class, I get lots of errors, like

`/usr/include/c++/v1/deque:907:49: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >'
    static const difference_type __block_size = sizeof(value_type) < 256 ? 4096 / sizeof(value_type) : 16;`

`/usr/include/c++/v1/deque:1181:30: error: '__alloc_traits' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__deque_base<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >'
    typedef typename __base::__alloc_traits        __alloc_traits;`

and so on.

It works when I use a vector, but I want a pop_front functionality.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Code:

```
#include <deque>
class Example {
    public:
        Example() {}
        ~Example() {}
    private:
        std::deque<std::string> m_deque;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include `#include <string>`

Comment: @gartenriese because `vector` includes string. I checked that for the VC runtime. The reason is that vector includes exception related headers.

Comment: @Paranaix Ok. I guess because I almost never have to include <string> when using string I just forgot about it eventually. Sorry for the rookie mistake! :(

Comment: @gartenriese its always good practice to include all classes directly you use in your declarations. 1) Other headers can always change independely from yours 2) Especially for standart classes: The includes inside the header files are implementation dependent, code compiling with VC could throw errors with GCC.